# Grails - MissingPropertyException error when trying to instantiate a File class object

Tags: grails, groovy

In a controller method, I'm trying to upload a image to replace an old image in a simple banner management system. This is the method:

```
def edit() {
    def banner = Banner.get(params.id)
    banner.clearErrors()
    banner.name = params.name

    def imgFile = request.getFile('imageUpload')
    if (!imgFile.empty) {
        def servletContext = ServletContextHolder.servletContext
        def oldImgPath = servletContext.getRealPath("images/banners/${banner.image}")
        banner.image = UploadFormService.getSafeFileName(imgFile.getOriginalFilename())
    }

    if (HomeService.saveBanner(banner)) {
        if (!imgFile.empty) {
            def oldImg = new File(oldImgPath)
            boolean oldImgStatus = oldImg.delete()
            imgFile.transferTo(new File("images/banners/${banner.image}"))
        }
        flash.message = "\"${banner.name}\" was successfully saved!"
    } else {
        flash.message = "NOK"
    }
    redirect(action:"index")
}
```

If `saveBanner(Banner banner)` returns `true` and if the form file input is not empty, the method should instantiate a Groovy File class using the current image, delete this current file from server and then transfer the new image to a server folder. But I have the following error:

> Error 500: Internal Server Error
>
> URI
>       /vs3/campanhas/editar/8 Class
>       groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException Message
>       No such property: oldImgPath for class: vs3.CampanhasController`
>   Around line 119 of
>   grails-app\controllers\vs3\CampanhasController.groovy

Line 119, in this case is `def oldImg = new File(oldImgPath)`

I've printed `oldImgPath` and the result was:

> C:\Grails_IDE\workspace\vs3\web-app\images\banners\fc712691a63824948c11a19569682803.jpg

...and this file exists, I can load it by my browsers normally.

**UP!**

I changed this line: 
`def oldImgPath = servletContext.getRealPath("images/banners/${banner.image}")` 
to 
`def oldImgPath = servletContext.getRealPath("web-app/images/banners/${banner.image}")`
...and I have the same error. 
And, just in case, `import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder was already included`.

Before that, what else should I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you defined the `def oldImgPath` in the scope of the 1st `if`-block, so it's invisible anywhere outside of it

Comment: I also kept `def oldImgPath = servletContext.getRealPath("images/banners/${banner.image}")` and it works fine now.